# 3 categorical IV and 1 categorical DV -- what test to use?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, categorical-data

Here's my setup:

Independent Variables (IV): 
(A) Task -- values 0 - 6 (order doesn't matter) 
(B) Viewpoint -- values 0 - 26 (order doesn't matter) 
(C) Input-device -- values {touchscreen, mouse, trackpad}

Dependent Variable (DV): 
(1) Types of drawing -- values {arrow, circle, outline, arrow+circle, arrow+outline, circle+outline, arrow+circle+outline, sketch, words, ...}

I want to see if task, viewpoint, or input-device affects the type of drawing my participants did. What statistical test should I use for this?

Since this is all categorical (nominal) data, I was thinking to use the Chi-Squared test, but I have too many independent variables, right? All the websites I have found mention using Chi-Squared with only 1 independent variable. I can't use a "Factorial logistic regression" either because the dependent variable is not dichotomous. Any ideas?

EDIT: Actually, I think my dependent variable is the number of each of type of drawing drawn. E.g., for Task 0, Viewpoint 1, mouse, across all users who did this task (it's between-subjects on Task), there was 3 arrows, 5 circles, etc. This is still a categorical DV, right?

Comment: I think that you need to clarify whether you really want to find out, if your IVs affect your DV, as, strictly speaking, this would be a _causal analysis_. Alternatively, your (most likely and simpler) goal is determine the nature of the relation between your IVs and your DV, which is a _correlational analysis_. But this is just my opinion.

Comment: Yes, I think I want the latter--just the nature of the relation between my IVs and my DV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you the following high-level **data analysis strategy/workflow**:

1. **Start** with performing [exploratory data analysis (EDA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploratory_data_analysis). This will provide you with a sense of your data set as well as reveal the data set's features, which might be helpful in further steps (assumptions, etc.).
2. **Perform** *regression analysis*. Your statement about inability of using logistic regression is incorrect, but this due to confusion that the term [logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) often is used to refer to a model with a **binary DV**. Indeed, *logistic regression* is applicable in your case and is referred to as [multinomial logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression), since your DV is of *unordered categorical type*. Should your DV be ordered, then that would be a case of an *ordered logistic regression*. The analysis IMHO should include evaluating the model's *goodness-of-fit (GoF)* and other relevant metrics (see above-referenced articles as a starting point, including for information on tests, etc.).
3. **Interpret** the *results of your analysis*, based on your research goals and questions.